# How can I store secrets in Jenkins DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a password that is required as an environment variable by one of my jenkins dsl jobs. The script 'build.sh' requires this password to be set, so I am storing it as a variable in passwords.groovy and passing it to the job as seen below.

```bash
    freeStyleJob('Myjobs') {
        environmentVariables {
            groovy(readFileFromWorkspace('env/passwords.groovy'))
        }
        steps {
            shell(readFileFromWorkspace('scripts/builds/build.sh'))
        }
    }
```

However, this means the password is in plaintext on the server and in the code itself where passwords.groovy is written.

What is a method to store secrets like this in jenkins dsl?

---

Edit:

So I think I see how to do this now.

Ok, so I think I see how to do this now.

The following addition to my job goes and looks for 'quay_credentials' which I can set up in the Jenkins web ui under job->configure->credentials->add.

```
wrappers {
    credentialsBinding {
        usernamePassword('userVariableName', 'passwordVariableName', 'quay_credentials')
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at the [credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/) which is designed to handle sensitive information

Comment: I am looking into this now, but finding the documentation quite lacking for how to implement this. I am not sure where the credentials would actually be provided to jenkins in this example: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.MavenWrapperContext.credentialsBinding